# Adding Padding and Border without messing up layout

Tags: css, layout, border, margin, padding

I have a 3 column layout with the following dimensions:

left column:240px;middle column:360px;right column:360px.I am using a 960px wrapper.

I created the layout using float and put in some placeholder text.I added a 10px right margin and a 1px solid border for all the columns by reducing each column width by 11px.I added a padding of 5px by applying the padding to the p and h elements, rather than the div( a tip I picked from Adobe DreamWeaver's built in 3 column layout, though I am not sure if it is a good practice).

For a fixed width layout all of this works perfectly fine, but what about a liquid/fluid layout? How would I add margin,border and padding without messing up the layout(I am using float:left to position the columns)?

Comment: JSFIDDLE would be nice

Comment: Why don't use `display: table`?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a great trick for adding padding and border(not margin) without messing up css width.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: The box-sizing property, does not include the margin. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your design @960width so you have change to right width:240px;
try below css :

```
#wrapper{
    width:960px;
}
.left{
    width:240px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
}
.middle{
    width:360px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
}
.right{
    width:240px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;

}
```

try below html :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="middle">middle</div>
     <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work..., but I don't want to change the relative width of my columns. The only reason I took away 10px from my column width, is that visually it makes a neglible(almost undetectable) difference. If I took away any further width from the columns, it would make a significant difference visually.That's why I added the padding to the h and p elements, rather than the div.

Comment: By the way the total width adds up to 240 + 240 + 360 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 1 + 1 + 1= 888px.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your design in liquid/fluid so follow below code.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-in">
        <div class="left">left</div>
        <div class="middle">middle</div>
        <div class="right">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{width:100%;}
.wrapper-in{width:1000px;}
.left{ width:218px; padding:5px; float:left; border:1px solid black; margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;}
.middle{width:338px; padding:5px; float:left; border:1px solid black; margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;}
.right{width:338px;padding:5px; float:left; border:1px solid black; margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;}
```

Comment: I've tried it...it doesn't work. You've added another wrapper with fluid width. But the width of the containers is fixed. I think that's the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
fixed width is main problem.
you can changed width size then checked.